# jQuery ui-datepicker-trigger error: 'J.inline' is null or not an object (happens on Mouseover)

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, jquery-ui, mouseover

I have two views that are using the same partial. This partial contains the jquery calendar. When the calendar icon is clicked and a date is selected in one view everything works fine but when clicked in another view and a date is selected I get this error in Visual Studio:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'J.inline' is null or not an object
```

and it jumps to this code in jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js

```
if(!d.datepicker._isDisabledDatepicker(J.inline?a.parent()[0]:J.input[0]))
```

Here is the code:

```
<p class="field date">
  <label for="StartDate-1">Exam Date</label>
  @DateEditor(new string[] { "StartDate", Model.ExamStart.ToString(),"UpdateDates();" })
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ExamStart)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ExamStart)
</p>
```

UPDATE: The error only occurs in one view when the calendar opens and I MOUSEOVER the specific days displayed in the calendar. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

some if the 1.816 ui.datepicker.css themes are causing this error (i got it using REDMOND)
I changed ui-lightness jquery.ui.datepicker.css and the problem went away.